# mail relay for multiple domains

Tags: linux, email, smtp

Is it possible to configure a postfix (or any other mailprogram for linux) in this way that it is able to recieves/send mails from and to multiple internet mailserver and deliver those mails to local network.

The idea behind it is that I'll set up all my mailaccounts (gmail, hotmail, etc.. ) on my linux machine as a relay account and I send all my mails to this relay and he'll forward it to the corresponding internet server.
The same for recieving mail from the internet account.

Could anyone please point me to a tutorial or man page.
Thanks indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending mails from local network to multiple ISPs you should configure relaymaps [This howto should be helpful](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-multiple-isp-accounts-smarthost-smtp-client/).

For receiving mail you can use fetchmail, al natxo asenjo suggested.

Answer (score 1):

so you want to pop mail from gmail/hotmail to your linux computer at home? Use fetchmail for that.

In order to have postfix relay mail in your home lan, consult the postfix docs: http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html , specially the standard configuration examples: http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Be advised that unless your isp has a very good reputation, if you try to be your own mail server you will be blocked by a lot of other mail servers. Use your isp smtp server to relay mail from your postfix server.